# $.getJSON não grava retorno em variáveis

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Criei uma função que pega os valores de um JSON e (deveria enviar esses valores para variáveis dentro da função) assim eu poderia usar essas variáveis na continuação da função. O problema é que quando executo a função ela não retorna os valores... se eu pego o código interno da mesma e executo no DOM ela funciona mas chamando ela não... Alguém me dá um help por favor?

```
    //get connection info's to access the system
    function connection(){

      //vars
      var servername;
      var database;
      var username;
      var password;

      //get JSON values
      $.getJSON('./data/configuration.json',function(data){
        servername = data.servername;
        database = data.database;
        username = data.username;
        password = data.password;
      });

      console.log(servername);
      console.log(database);
      console.log(username);
      console.log(password);
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O problema é que o `getJSON` é uma operação **assíncrona**, o que significa que ela não é completada imediatamente. O código que vem depois do `getJSON` (o que inclui seus `console.log` e o próprio retorno de `connection`) executa antes do JSON chegar.

Por isso você passa uma função como segundo parâmetro, pois é garantido que ela irá executar somente quando os dados estiverem disponíveis.

Ou seja: você só pode usar os dados após o recebimento dos mesmos. Sugiro dividir seu código em funções menores, e chamar a função responsável por tratar os dados quando eles estiverem disponíveis.

Por exemplo:

```
//get connection info's to access the system
function connection(){
  //get JSON values
  $.getJSON('./data/configuration.json',function(data){
    usaDados(data);
  });
}

function usaDados(dados) {
  console.log(dados.servername);
  console.log(dados.database);
  console.log(dados.username);
  console.log(dados.password);
}
```

Você também pode alterar a função mais externa para receber um callback:

```
//get connection info's to access the system
function connection(callback){
  //get JSON values
  $.getJSON('./data/configuration.json', callback);
}

function usaDados(dados) {
  console.log(dados.servername);
  console.log(dados.database);
  console.log(dados.username);
  console.log(dados.password);
}

// LEIA: assim que obtiver a conexão, usa os dados
connection(usaDados);
```